# Plotly change font and background color when hovering dropdown button

Tags: python, html, css, plotly

Is there a way to add custom CSS to Plotly dropdown buttons?
I have the following ones:

```
...
updatemenus=[
  dict(buttons=[
    dict(
      args=["type", "bar"],
      label="Bar Chart",
      method="restyle",
    ),
    dict(
      args=["type", "scatter"],
      label="Line Chart",
      method="restyle",
    )
  ]
  , direction="down"),
...
```

But when using a figure with the theme **plotly_dark**, this is how they look like when ***hovering***:
[image]

I saw properties bgcolor, bordercolor, borderwidth... but nothing regarding hover styling.
Anyone was able to make it work?

Thank you

Comment: +1 Looking for an answer for this as well. Looks like these buttons are designed for default/white backgrounds only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
font = dict(color='#000000')
```

For example,

```
...
updatemenus=[
  dict(buttons=[
    dict(
      args=["type", "bar"],
      label="Bar Chart",
      method="restyle",
    ),
    dict(
      args=["type", "scatter"],
      label="Line Chart",
      method="restyle",
      )
    ],
  direction="down",
  font = dict(color='#000000'),
  ),
...
```